# If $X\sim exp(\lambda)$ what is the PDF of $X^2$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X\sim exp(\lambda)$ what is the Probability density function of $X^2$?
I'd like to know how to calculate it, and what is the way...

Thank you!

Comment: probability-theory, statistics, really? @Tunk-Fey.

Comment: @StefanHansen Feel free to edit if I made mistakes. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $X\sim$ exponential distribution $(\lambda)$. The CDF of $X$ is
$$
F_X(x)=\Pr[X\le x]=1-e^{\large-\lambda x}.
$$
Let $Y=X^2$, then the CDF of $Y$ is
$$
\begin{align}
F_Y(y)&=\Pr[Y\le y]\\
&=\Pr\left[X^2\le y\right]\\
&=\Pr[X\le \sqrt{y}]\\
&=F_X(\sqrt{y})\\
&=1-e^{\large-\lambda \sqrt{y}}.
\end{align}
$$
Using the CDF of $y$, we can easily obtain that $Y\sim$ [Weibull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\right)$. The PDF can also easily be found using
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y).
$$

Comment: What is Weibull $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{\lambda^2}\right)$??

Comment: I saw your edit - we didn't learn it :-(

Comment: @Yoar Click the given link. It's Weibull distribution with parameters $k=\dfrac12$ and $\lambda=\dfrac1{\lambda^2}$ according to Wikipedia notation.

Comment: Yes, I clicked on the link, but we didn't learn it...
Can I skip it? or I must mention it?

Comment: @Yoar You can skip it. All you need is only the PDF of $Y$, which can be found from my answer.

Comment: So the PDF is: $$f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y)??$$ This is the final answer?

Comment: @Yoar Yup! Just find the derivative of the CDF. It's easy job.

Comment: So it's: $$(1-e^{\large-\lambda \sqrt{y}})'??$$

Comment: If yes, we get something wired: $$\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda\sqrt y}}{2\sqrt y}$$

Comment: @Yoar Just click the link of Weibull and plug in $k=\dfrac12$ & $\lambda=\dfrac1{\lambda^2}$ to the PDF of Weibull.

Comment: I try, but I didn't found a place that I can put those values...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** One way that you could find this would be to find the cumulative distribution function for $X^2$, then use it to find the probability density function.

To find the CDF for $X^2$, note that $X$ is non-negative; so
$$
P(X^2\leq x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if }x<0\\P(X\leq\sqrt{x}) & \text{if }x\geq0\end{cases}.
$$
(If we didn't have a non-negative random variable, we would have to be more careful here; in fact, we would get
$$
P(X^2\leq x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if }x<0\\P(-\sqrt{x}\leq X\leq\sqrt{x}) & \text{if }x\geq0\end{cases},
$$
which then simplifies to our answer by noting that in that case, $P(-\sqrt{x}\leq X\leq\sqrt{x})=P(X\leq\sqrt{x})$ for $x\geq 0$.)

Once you've found the CDF, do you know how to find the density?

Comment: I don't think so, I'd like to get help from you...

Comment: Remember that $X\sim exp(\lambda)$ and I need to use this fact...

Comment: Obviously, you'll need to use the specific distribution.  But given the method that I've pointed out, this will not be very difficult.

Comment: Please tell me if I'm right: $$X^2\sim exp(\sqrt\lambda)$$ Right??

Comment: Or this: $$\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda\sqrt y}}{2\sqrt y}$$ Please tell me which one of them is right.... Thank you!

Comment: The latter is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If $Y=X^2$ and $u$ is a bounded, measurable function, then
$$
{\rm E}[u(Y)]=\int_0^\infty u(x^2)\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,\mathrm dx.
$$
Now, do a change of variables with $y=x^2$ to obtain something of the form
$$
\int_0^\infty u(y)v(y)\,\mathrm dy
$$
for some function $v$ (to be determined by you) and conclude that the density of $Y$ is $y\mapsto v(y)\mathbf{1}_{y>0}$.

Comment: But i need to find the PDF, not E()....

Comment: Read the last sentence. The density of any random variable $Y$ is the unique function $v$ satisfying ${\rm E}[u(Y)]=\int u(y)v(y)\,\mathrm dy$ for all bounded, measurable $u$.

Comment: I still not understand how I'm getting from it the PDF, I don't understand what I need to do....

Comment: Do you know how to do a change of variables of the first integral by putting $y=x^2$?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how does it's helps me...

Comment: It helps you the following way: when you have done the change of variable, and arrived at an integral of the form $\int_0^\infty u(y) v(y)\,\mathrm dy$ where $v(y)$ can be _anything_, then you may conclude that $y\mapsto v(y)\mathbf{1}_{y>0}$ is the density of $Y=X^2$.